# Magento - How to get id of newly created Credit Memo within save after observer?

Tags: magento

I have set up a `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after` observer within a custom module. I'm then using...

```
$creditmemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
$data = $creditmemo->getData();
```

...to get details of the credit memo just created (saved). However, neither the increment_id or id of the newly created credit memo seem to be made available, only details of the order/invoice that the credit memo relates to.

How can I get the id of the credit memo itself, e.g. credit memo #**200000045**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried:

`$incrementId = $creditmemo->getIncrementId();`

Comment: Many thanks @teknoman - this did the trick. I thought I'd already tried this, but anyway it seems to work now.